# Rolling column comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'd like to work with comparing "n column" to "n-1 column":

Dataset:

```
data = {"Week_1": [np.nan,1,0,0,0,np.nan],
        "Week_2": [0,0,0,1,1,0],
        "Week_3": [0,0,1,1,1,np.nan],
        "Week_4": [0,0,1,1,0,1],
        "Week_5": [0,1,0,0,1,0],
       }

idx = ["Employee_1", "Employee_2", "Employee_3", "Employee_4", "Employee_5", "Employee_6"]

data = pd.DataFrame(data,
                    index=idx
                   )
```

What it looks like:

```
            Week_1  Week_2  Week_3  Week_4  Week_5
Employee_1  NaN     0       0.0     0       0
Employee_2  1.0     0       0.0     0       1
Employee_3  0.0     0       1.0     1       0
Employee_4  0.0     1       1.0     1       0
Employee_5  0.0     1       1.0     0       1
Employee_6  NaN     0       NaN     1       0
```

What I'm expecting to get:

```
            Week_1  Week_2          Week_3          Week_4          Week_5
Employee_1  NaN     Not Applicable  Same            Same            Same
Employee_2  NaN     Regress         Same            Same            Improve
Employee_3  NaN     Same            Improve         Same            Regress
Employee_4  NaN     Improve         Same            Same            Regress
Employee_5  NaN     Improve         Same            Regress         Improve
Employee_6  NaN     Not Applicable  Not Applicable  Not Applicable  Regress
```

What my code looks like:

Function:

```
def compare(val):
    
     conditions = [val[0] > val[1],
                   val[0] < val[1],
                   val[0] == val[1],
                   np.nan in val
                  ]

     choices = ["Improve", "Regress", "Same", "Not Applicable"]

     return np.select(conditions, choices, np.nan)
```

1st attempt:

```
data.rolling(2, axis=1).apply(compare)
```

2nd attempt:

```
data.rolling(2, axis=1).apply(lambda x: compare(x))
```

Comment: the original values will always be 0,1 and nan or you can have more values?

Comment: @Ben.T, you can have more values..that's something that I consider also from the function I made..thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can change your function `compare`, and passing the `diff` of data.

```
def compare(df_):
    
     conditions = [df_>0, df_<0, df_==0]

     choices = ["Improve", "Regress", "Same"]

     return pd.DataFrame(np.select(conditions, choices, "Not Applicable"), 
                         index=df_.index, columns=df_.columns)

res = compare(data.diff(axis=1))

print(res)
                    Week_1          Week_2          Week_3          Week_4  \
Employee_1  Not Applicable  Not Applicable            Same            Same   
Employee_2  Not Applicable         Regress            Same            Same   
Employee_3  Not Applicable            Same         Improve            Same   
Employee_4  Not Applicable         Improve         Regress            Same   
Employee_5  Not Applicable         Improve            Same         Regress   
Employee_6  Not Applicable  Not Applicable  Not Applicable  Not Applicable   

             Week_5  
Employee_1     Same  
Employee_2  Improve  
Employee_3  Regress  
Employee_4  Regress  
Employee_5  Improve  
Employee_6  Regress
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing "n column" to "n-1 column" simply means `diff` with `axis=1`:

```
s = data.diff(axis=1)

data.loc[:] = np.select([s>=1, s==0, s<0], ["Increase","Same","Regress"], "Not Applicable")

print (data)

                    Week_1          Week_2          Week_3          Week_4    Week_5
Employee_1  Not Applicable  Not Applicable            Same            Same      Same
Employee_2  Not Applicable         Regress            Same            Same  Increase
Employee_3  Not Applicable            Same        Increase            Same   Regress
Employee_4  Not Applicable        Increase            Same            Same   Regress
Employee_5  Not Applicable        Increase            Same         Regress  Increase
Employee_6  Not Applicable  Not Applicable  Not Applicable  Not Applicable   Regress
```

Comment: hello henry, this really solves the problem based from example. but can you provide an alternative? suppose the values range from (1-10)? instead of (1s and 0s)